# SQL - Request to long - Which index should I create?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table called eod, with more than 1,5M row, and there is a sample of it. (I'm using MySQL)

```
| eod_id | company_symbol |    date    | open  | close | high  |  low  | volume |
|      1 |            AAA | 01-01-2000 | 40.00 | 42.00 | 43.00 | 39.00 | 100000 |
```

I want to do this request, but it takes more than 4 seconds:

```
SELECT company_symbol,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CLOSE < OPEN THEN 1 END) AS 'Green Days',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN OPEN < CLOSE THEN 1 END) AS 'Red Days',
  COUNT(volume) AS 'Volume'
FROM eod
GROUP BY company_symbol;
```

This is the result of the explain :

```
id : 1
select_type : SIMPLE
table : eod
type : index
possible_keys : NULL
key : eos_cs_date
key_len : 57
ref : NULL
rows : 1536743
```

I have already create those 2 indexes for other requests :

```
create index eod_date_close on eod(date, close);
create index eod_cs_date on eod(company_symbol, date);
```

What could I do to decrease the request time please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My first try would be an index on company_symbol.  What RDBMS are you using, most of them have some sort of query tuning capability.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Only on company_symbol ? I tried, it doesn't change

Comment: I'm more of a PostgreSQL user, but over in that database, I believe that `CASE` can defeat some optimization attempts. Perhaps they do in MySQL as well. Maybe you can convert the query to some kind of `GROUP BY` on the comparison? Can MySQL do indexes on calculated values?

Comment: your likely going to need a key on open and close

Comment: Also, what's `volume`? It's not in your table.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this column, I added it. What do you mean by convert the query ?

Comment: Case is going to be very expensive, does MySQL support storing computed columns in table?  I have used that on mssql in the past, but it is dirty.